# VBA macro filter in search highlight string

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am searching a long MS Word document for words that end in `ly` and highlighting them yellow.

However, certain words that end in `ly` are not adverbs (only, family) and I want to skip those.

How do I mod my code logic to do this:

```
If word=TargetList Then [If word=ExceptionList Then Skip ] Else [ highlight ]
```

Is a filter statement needed?

```
Sub FindAdverbs()
    '
    ' FindAdverbs Macro
    '
    '
    Dim range As range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim TargetList

    TargetList = Array("ly") ' 'string to search for
    ExceptionList = Array("family", "only") 'string of words to ignore

    For i = 0 To UBound(TargetList)
        Set range = ActiveDocument.range
        With range.Find
            .Text = TargetList(i)
            .Format = True
            .MatchCase = True
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
            Do While .Execute(Forward:=True) = True
                range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
            Loop
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Side Note: I hardly recommend not to use reserved words like `Range` as variable names: Instead of `Dim range As range` always use variable names different from any reserved word like `Dim myRange As Range`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code. Apart from what @Peh said about using reserved words for naming variables, I have avoided the use of variants. MS Word is about text and text is contained in strings. To use them is both easier and more efficient when manipulating texts.

```
Sub FindAdverbs()
' 03 Jun 2017

Dim Targets() As String
Dim Exceptions As String
Dim Rng As Range
Dim LastFound As Long, RngEnd As Long
Dim n As Long
Dim i As Long

Targets = Split("ly,lo", ",")                       'string to search for
Exceptions = "family,only"                          'string of words to ignore

For i = 0 To UBound(Targets)
    Set Rng = ActiveDocument.Content
    With Rng.Find
        .Text = "*" & Targets(i)
        .MatchCase = True
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Format = False
        .Forward = True
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        Do
            .Execute
            With Rng
                If (.End <= LastFound) Then Exit Do

                LastFound = .End
                RngEnd = .End
                .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
                .MoveStart wdWord, -1
                n = .MoveEndUntil(".,;:!?" & Chr(9) & Chr(10) & Chr(11) & Chr(12) & Chr(13) & Chr(32))
                If (InStr(1, Exceptions, Trim(.Text), vbTextCompare) = 0) And (n = 1) Then
                    .HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
                End If
                .SetRange RngEnd, RngEnd
            End With
        Loop While .Found
    End With
Next i
```

End Sub

As another change I made which is worthy of your attention is in the line `.Text = "*" & Targets(i)`. This will ensure that words containing "ly" in a position other than at the end will not be turned up by the search.

Comment: That worked brilliantly. In addition it ran much faster than my version. It ignored lye and lyrics but flagged tallyho, I'm not sure why. Words with LY embedded in them are very few so I'm not fussed.

Comment: I said that the code would ignore embedded search criteria and it didn't. Sorry about that. I have posted improved code. In the process I found that the `MatchWholeWord` property is without effect when wild cards are used, but the `MatchCase` property is effective and I have set it to `True` to avoid finding "LY", which has a positive and negative side depending upon whether the text includes allcaps. You can extend the list of characters in `MoveEndUntil` to include more characters that might follow the end of a word in your texts. Point is, if "ly" isn't at the end it must be embedded.